# What is actual purpose of getclass() in ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("imagepath"))

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I was going through ImageIO, and I read this code on web, but could not figure out why getClass() is needed in this scenario. (getClass() returns the classname as far as I have understood -> correct me if I am wrong). so, why we need getClass() here?

Comment: Well, you are wrong. It dosn't get the class name, it gets the class **object**. You need a class object or a class loader object to get a resource.

Answer (score 1):

The `.getResource()` method of a `Class<?>` object (which is what any `.getClass()` call will return) ultimately calls upon the `ClassLoader` of the running JVM; and you *need* a `ClassLoader` in order to access resources in your running class path.

This is documented in [the relevant javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-):

> Finds a resource with a given name. The rules for searching resources associated with a given class are implemented by the defining class loader of the class.